# How to convert the excel input of yyyy-mm-dd-HH.mm.ss.000000 into "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM"

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have excel cell with the input of yyyy-mm-dd-HH.mm.ss.000000

Now I would like to chnage my input into "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM"

I tried few of the custom setting option few formulas given in forums .. but no luck.. Any idea how convert the data into destination format using Excel formula option?

Comment: Do you want to convert or view it differently? Viewing is through Custom Setting, while converting will be through a formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that the input date is in text format as you mentioned that using a custom format doesn't work.

So, you'll have to work with the string a bit. If you want to keep the seconds in the value but display only up to the minutes, you can use:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(I4,"-"," ",3),".",":",1),".",":",1)*1
```

And then use the Custom format to make it display the way you want it to. Otherwise, it'll display as a bunch of numbers such as 41440.5625.

If you don't need the seconds or anything beyond, you can use:

```
=LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(I4,"-"," ",3),".",":"),16)*1
```

And once again use the custom format.

The substitute first replaces the 3rd instance of `-` by a white space to separate the date from the time, and the second one replaces all the periods `.` by colons `:` so that it's a readable datetime format for excel. The `*1` converts the resulting string into number understood as date by excel which you only have to format. Otherwise, if you want to get a text output, drop the `*1` at the end altogether.